# Nifi:SSL Context Service error

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi

I have download  cer  file  from browser  (i mean i downloaded ssl  certificate  for my  secure nifi) and  imported  it into cacerts.jks  then i want to add  this  truststore ito SSL Context Service truststore and made  this service  enable for ssl  handshake but it still shows me that: truststore file validated agains cacerts.jks it is invalid because fail doesn't exist or can't be read , jks  isn't  corrupted i can see  it's   content  by keytool -list , what should  i change to make service enable?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the path to this file is absolute rather than relative and that the password is correct.

If you have not changed the password, it will be "changeit".

Comment: In my case, the validation never passes, despite giving the correct path of the JKS file. I use the same path in Spark and there it works perfectly.